# Is there any tool can adding metadata into mpegts file like mediafilesegmenter in MacOS platform?

Tags: mpeg

As mentioned in the title...

Currently, I want to adding some metadata information(like ID3 tag) into mpegts file which can make the client player play the mpegts file and read the injected information at the same time.

On the MaxOS platform, we can use mediafilesegmenter to add some ID3 tag by the command of "mediafilesegmenter -M metafile file". And then, the ios device can play the modified ts file and also can read the added string correctly.

However, I really need a tool which can do the similar thing under linux platform. For example, adding the artist name, album name, etc. into the ts file.

Any suggestion? I really need some help!

Answer (score -2):

ffprobe should be able to handle this, it's part of the ffmpeg.

Comment: An example would've been nice.

Comment: ffprobe can't add metadata, I'm afraid.